# How to read(get) the Y-Axis Scale Values(Min&Max) from Excel Chart using c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

Is there any way to get the **Y-Axis** `Min & Max` values from the `Excel Chart` using `C#`, I've the following chart which is drawn using set of values in C#, and exported into .xls file.

[image]

Now I want to read the `Y-Axis Scale Min & Max` values in `C#`

**`EDIT:`**

[image]

any help on this would be much appreciated, Thanks.!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(chart.Axes(2).MinimumScale);` works for me when referencing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library - what version are you referencing?

Comment: Description: Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library, Version: 1.5.0.0, I did try by including the reference but no luck so far, thanks again for your help...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(1,1,100,100);
chartPage = myChart.Chart;
Excel.Axis yAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue);
yAxis.MinimumScale = 0.0;
yAxis.MaximumScale = 30;
yAxis.MajorUnit = 5;
yAxis.MinorUnit = 1;
```